# How do you see what responsibilities are present in your version of the e-Business suite?

Tags: oracle11g, bi-publisher

Just curious , my boss asked me to "see what responsibilities are present " in the Oracle  e-Business suite .   For example , maybe we have XML BI Publisher, Order Management, etc  responsibilities .

I'm not exactly sure where to go to find this information?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the auditing reports (log with a system or audit responsibility). Or query `applsys.fnd_login_responsibilities`.

If you need to see whether someone has ever connected using a specific responsibility, you need to enable logon auditing and then run the reports after the event. Note that legal labor restrictions may apply in your company which forbid enabling auditing login events.

For more information, see for instance [Apps manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12843/T156458T156462.htm).